# Pattern to create an object and populate its properties in other methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have created a Photo class which contains a lot of properties such as size, filename, latitude/longitude, location etc.

```
public class Photo {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime CapturedDate { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create an object of this class and populate its properties in a step by step approach, where each step needs to perform some kind of operation before setting some of the values on the object.

In a quick and dirty solution to make this work I simply created some void methods to fill the object properties, but I think this is anti-pattern.

```
var photo = new Photo();
photo.FileName = "Photo 1"
SetExifData(photo, photoStream);
SetLocationName(photo);
DoSomethingElse(photo);

void SetExifData(Photo photo, Stream photoStream) {
   //Read exit data from the photo stream and update the object
   photo.Latitude = "10,0";
   photo.Longitude = "10,0";
   photo.CapturedDate = ....
}
void SetLocationName(Photo photo){
   //Call external API to get location name from lat/lng
   photo.LocationName = "London"
}
void DoSomethingElse(Photo photo){
}
```

It would be optimal to pass this object to a kind of pipeline or builder. What pattern would be suitable for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Only from what you've told me, a builder pattern might be the way to go. This can be created to support a fluent interface (if sufficient for your Pipeline needs), or as an intermediate step for use when setting up a more specialized Pipeline pattern.

```
class PhotoBuilder
{
   // All properties goes here
   private string Latitude { get; set; }
   private string Longitude { get; set; }
   ...

   public PhotoBuilder WithExifDataFromStream(Stream photoStream)
   {
      Latitude = ...;
      Longitude = ...;
      ...
      return this;
   }

   public Photo Build() => return new Photo(...);
}
```

I would advice to hide all state in the builder and only create the object at the end as a read-only object. It makes for much simpler reasoning.

The slightly less attractive alternative would be to hide your setters as internal and use them from the builder. I tend to stay away from such internals as far as possible for purity reasons, but YMMV. It certainly helps for very large structures. Even with this approach I would urge you to only expose the object at the end to keep the separation of the builder and the object itself. Also make sure you pass out an "immutable" object, I.E. clear up any references to that photo as soon as `Build` is called to avoid inadvertently changing the object post build.

***Idle musings:***

I have found it good to be fairly restrictive on the kind of logic you put in such a builder to start with. Of course this will depend on your use-case, but in larger systems certain logic will often be used in many places and I have had more than once had headaches over refactoring out multi-purpose functionality from an interface which was not as clean as it could be.

In this case, this could translate to `SetLocation(double longitude, double latitude, string locationName)` and `WithCaptureDate(...)`. This would enable the builder to be used in more scenarios, and enables you to create special functions on top of it later if need be.

I've found it also helps in Unit Testing and composition. For example, you do not bind your builder to a Location API. This can also be solved with Dependency Injection, of course (`ILocationResolver` or similar), but then you *might* be looking at an object which is invalidating the Single-Responsibility principle.

In the end, it is very dependent on the system you are building and the requirements for this particular class. I would err on the side of creating another wrapper which does all the location and stream parsing stuff, but that is comming from someone who mostly deals with large interconnected systems where functionality reuse and composability requirements are high. If the system is very small, this may only introduce unwanted complexity.